# How to insert a given description when there is a certain character in the row of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following tables that are created from certain files:

table1.csv:

```
cod description
101 some description1
102 some description2
201 some description3
212 some description5
301 some description76
302 some description23
411 some description45
512 some description12
```

table2.txt:

```
cod title
0   title1
1   title2
2   title14
3   title17
4   title13
5   title19
```

Code that inserted this data into variables:

```
table1 <- read.table("table1.csv",sep="\t",
                    header = TRUE,na.strings = '', colClasses = NA)

table2 <- read.table("table2.txt", sep = "\t",header = TRUE)
```

So what I want, and I do not know how to do, is that the description that has code 1, from table2, is inserted into table1, where the first character of the HEADER code is 1, too, and so on. Where the description, in table1, has code 2, is inserted in table2, where the first character of the HEADER code, is 2, too. And so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry, I mean, HEADER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `within` and `match` `cod` from `table2` with 1<sup>st</sup> `substr`ing of `cod` from `table1`.

```
table1 <- within(table1, {
  new <- table2$description[match(substr(table1$cod, 1, 1), table2$cod)]
})
table1
#   cod        description     new
# 1 101  some description1  title2
# 2 102  some description2  title2
# 3 201  some description3 title14
# 4 212  some description5 title14
# 5 301 some description76 title17
# 6 302 some description23 title17
# 7 411 some description45 title13
# 8 512 some description12 title19   

table2 <- within(table2, {
  new <- table1$description[match(table2$cod, substr(table1$cod, 1, 1))]
})
table2
#   cod description                new
# 1   0      title1               <NA>
# 2   1      title2  some description1
# 3   2     title14  some description3
# 4   3     title17 some description76
# 5   4     title13 some description45
# 6   5     title19 some description12
```

#### Data

```
table1 <- structure(list(cod = structure(1:8, .Label = c("101", "102", 
"201", "212", "301", "302", "411", "512", "cod"), class = "factor"), 
    description = structure(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("description", 
    "some description1", "some description12", "some description2", 
    "some description23", "some description3", "some description45", 
    "some description5", "some description76"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

table2 <- structure(list(cod = structure(1:6, .Label = c("0", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "cod"), class = "factor"), description = structure(c(2L, 
7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("title", "title1", "title13", 
"title14", "title17", "title19", "title2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```